# button disable with jquery validation

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to disable enable a button with jQuery validation plugin. In my project works when I write in the first input but when I focus out it doesn't work as in this example

[code_example](http://jsfiddle.net/p628Y/1/)

I made this fiddle [my_fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/novita2020/4v0tfroh/7/) to show you what's going on. When I delete the information from the input the    button doesn't disable.

Thank in advance for your help

```
    $('#ethForm').validate({
        rules: {
            ethIpAdress: {
                required: true,
            },
            ethNetMask: {
                required: true,
            },
            ethNetMask: {
                required: true,
            },
            ethDns: {
                required: true,
            },
        }
    });

    $('#ethForm input').on('keyup blur', function () {
        if ($('#ethForm').valid()) {
            $('#formSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#formSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery validator use `name`, not `id` to select inputs : https://jsfiddle.net/5rucebhL/

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `id` of the `input` elements to `name` worked:

```
<div class="formEth">
  <h2>Ethernet Configuration</h2>
  <form id="ethForm">
    <input type="checkbox" id="ethDHCP" value="first_checkbox" onchange="valueChangedEth()"> DHCP Configuration
    <br>
    <div class="inputContainer ethHide">
      <label for="ethIpAdress">Ip Adress</label><br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ethIpAdress">
    </div>
    <div class="inputContainer ethHide">
      <label for="ethNetMask">Netmask </label><br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ethNetMask">
    </div>
    <div class="inputContainer ethHide">
      <label for="ethGateWay">Gateway</label><br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ethGateWay">
    </div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <label for="ethDns">DNS</label><br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ethDns">
    </div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <label for="ethMetric">Metric</label><br>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="ethMetric">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="submit" id="formSubmit" disabled="disabled">SEND</button>
</div>
```